Log a call adding additional fields
Is there a way to add fields here? 
I would like to see if I can add additional information so that I no longer need to open the Task to see the fields I want to check.
Thanks in advance. All of your insights will be much appreciated

This is controlled by the Task object's Compact Layout - changing the fields which displayed on the layout will adjust how they appear in the feed.
There are some limitations to this, outlined in this Idea.
